# how to join table using alias without prefix in lumen

Tags: php, mysql, database, alias, lumen

it is my active sql:

```
SELECT sag.goods_id, if(sa.status=3, 1, 0) AS act_status 
FROM d_seckill_activity_goods AS sag LEFT JOIN d_seckill_activity AS sa ON sa.id = sag.sa_id
WHERE sa.id = 1
```

Then i need it using DB in lumen
so i write like this:

```
$prefix = env('DB_PREFIX');
DB::table('seckill_activity_goods as sag')
    ->leftJoin('seckill_activity as sa', 'sa.id', '=', 'sag.sa_id')
    ->select('sag.goods_id', DB::raw("if({$prefix}sa.status=3, 1, 0) AS act_status"))
    ->first();
```

luckly it work well, but i hate the $prefix variable,

is it another way using DB ?

Comment: I do not really understand that $prefix at all. In the native sql statement there is nothing before `sa.status` in the expression. What do you use it for and what happens if you just remove $prefix from your php code?

Comment: @Shadow, remove $prefix, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sa.status' in 'field list' (SQL: select `d_sag`.`goods_id`, if(sa.status=3, 1, 0) AS act_status from `d_seckill_activity_goods` as `d_sag` left join `d_seckill_activity` as `d_sa` on `d_sa`.`id` = `d_sag`.`sa_id` limit 1)